# Do we want to participate in the 1 rep voting cap experiment?

Tags: discussion, voting, reputation

This [Meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on?cb=1) here explains in detail.

Obviously this site is far less trafficked than others, so it may not fairly represent either the positive or negative aspects of this idea. It would be good to get some opinions on the possibility.

Comment: You may want to add the [featured] tag (at some point) to ensure that the discussion is more visible to the community as a whole, since there hasn't been much of a response to this post from the community so far. I'd also encourage community members to post their arguments (for or against Expatriates SE testing this out) as answers.